# implementation of Message queue

Tags: c++

I have implemented a message queue for inter thread communication just like POSIX message queue. I want to know whether there is any scope for performance improvement and also any bugs which need to be corrected. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::list<std::vector<char>> msg_queue;

void recv() {
    char buff[2048];
    
    while(true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul { mu };
        
        while(msg_queue.empty())
            cv.wait(ul);
            
        std::vector<char>& queue_msg = msg_queue.front();
        if(queue_msg.size() < sizeof(buff)) {
            std::memcpy(buff, queue_msg.data(), queue_msg.size());
            buff[queue_msg.size()] = '\0';
        }
        
        msg_queue.pop_front();
        
        ul.unlock();
        
        std::cout << buff << std::endl;
    }
}

int32_t main() {
    const char *data = "Hello world!";
    std::thread th(recv);
    
    while(true) {
        mu.lock();
        
        msg_queue.emplace_back(std::vector<char>(data, data + strlen(data)));
        cv.notify_one();
        
        mu.unlock();
        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    
    th.join();
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  It would help reviewers if you could provide an example of how this code is intended to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you’re primarily interested in efficiency, that’s what I’m going to focus on in my review.

However, first I do need to point out that `int32_t main()` is not legal C++. I’m mildly surprised it even compiles. There are only two legal forms of `main()`:

- `int main()`; and
- `int main(int, char*[])`.

I should also mention that a message queue is probably better done as a class, with the mutex and other implementation details as private data members, rather than as global variables, and details like notifying the condition variable handled automatically. But that isn’t a performance issue, just a design one.

```
std::list<std::vector<char>> msg_queue;
```

Using a `std::list` for the actual queue is an odd choice. It’s not *wrong*; it’ll work perfectly fine. And `std::list` is not the most performant container, but its inefficiencies will be absolutely *dwarfed* by all the thread context switching and locking/unlocking.

Normally for a message queue like this you’d use a `std::vector`, or maybe a `std::deque`. Or sometimes you’d actually use a `std::array` (or a `std::vector` with a fixed size), and either treat it like a ring buffer—so if there are too many unhandled messages, older messages get lost—or block any new messages until some older messages are handled.

As I said, `std::list` isn’t *wrong*. It’ll work. I just don’t see any *benefits* to using it, because at least in the example code, you don’t really benefit from iterator stability (which is the primary reason to prefer a `std::list`), and you’ll pay a lot more for allocations and cache misses.

```
char buff[2048];
```

Is there a reason you use a fixed-size buffer? I don’t see any performance gains from it, and you’ll just lose any messages longer than 2k.

I’ll offer alternative suggestions later.

```
while(true) {
```

<del>You have a bug in your program in that the loops are infinite. Infinite loops are UB.</del> (Correction: Infinite loops are UB if and only if they have no observable side effects. These loops have side effects (like printing to standard out, and locking mutexes). However, there is no portable way to end the program, and—more importantly (because it’s the subject of the review)—the message queue. If you tried to put this message queue as-is in an existing program, like the example one, it will never end; it will deadlock while waiting for the thread to join, while the thread loops and waits on the condition variable.)

What you really need is a way for the `recv()` function to realize the program’s ending. For example, you could use a message "done" as a signal to wind things up:

```
// in recv()
while (true)
{
    // ... [snip] ...

    if (buf == "done")
        break;
}

// in main()
for (auto n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) // instead of while (true)
{
    // ... [snip] ...
}

// artificial scope
{
    auto lock = std::scoped_lock(mu);
    msg_queue.emplace_back({'d', 'o', 'n', 'e'});
}

cv.notify_one();

th.join();
```

It doesn’t need to be a special message to signal the end, but if you use something else, like a flag, then you might need to be sure you finish handling all the messages before ending the `recv()` loop, and you need to consider what happens if the flag is set while the queue is empty (and the condition variable is waiting on it to *not* be empty).

```
while(msg_queue.empty())
    cv.wait(ul);
```

Rather than a manual loop like this, it’s cleaner and less likely to cause problems if you use the other form of `wait()` that takes a lambda:

```
cv.wait(ul, [] { return not msg_queue.empty(); });
```

This removes the temptation for some later code monkey to fool with the loop in some way. Raw loops are a code smell, because you should generally prefer algorithms. They’re fine in the use cases here, but you never know what some future coder might think to do. Also, this reads much clearer, even to someone who doesn’t understand condition variables (who might ask, “why a loop *and* a call to a wait function?”).

```
std::vector<char>& queue_msg = msg_queue.front();
if(queue_msg.size() < sizeof(buff)) {
    std::memcpy(buff, queue_msg.data(), queue_msg.size());
    buff[queue_msg.size()] = '\0';
}

msg_queue.pop_front();
```

Okay, here’s where the biggest inefficiencies lie. I don’t see a reason—at least in this code—why you copy the message from the message queue into a buffer, then delete the message from the queue. Why not just *take* the message right from the queue and use it?

In other words, why not do this:

```
void recv()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul { mu };
        cv.wait(ul, [] { return not msg_queue.empty(); });

        // *TAKE* the message from the queue. This will be *LIGHTNING* quick;
        // possibly *thousands* of times faster than copying the message into a
        // buffer.
        auto queue_msg = std::move(msg_queue.front());

        // Remove it from the list.
        msg_queue.pop_front();

        // No need to hold the lock anymore.
        ul.unlock();

        // Now you have the message as queue_msg, and you can do whatever you want
        // with it. For example, print it:
        std::cout.write(queue_msg.data(), queue_msg.size());
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

But that’s just the tip of the performance iceberg. It’s very wasteful to do all that locking and so on for *ONE* message at a time. What if there are several messages in the queue? Why not handle them all at once?

For example:

```
void recv()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul { mu };
        cv.wait(ul, [] { return not msg_queue.empty(); });

        // Take the ENTIRE QUEUE. Even if there are multiple messages, this could
        // still be thousands of times faster than copying a SINGLE message into a
        // buffer, and that's not even taking into account the gains you get from
        // avoiding multiple locking and unlocking and waiting cycles.
        auto messages = std::vector<std::vector<char>>{};
        messages.resize(msg_queue.size()); // make space for the messages
        std::move(msg_queue.begin(), msg_queue.end(), messages.begin()); // move them all out of the queue
        msg_queue.clear(); // clear the queue of the (now empty, moved-from) messages

        // No need for the lock anymore.
        ul.unlock();

        // Now we can handle all the messages at our leisure.
        std::for_each(messages.begin(), messages.end(),
            [](auto&& message)
            {
                std::cout.write(message.data(), message.size());
                std::cout << '\n';
            });
    }
}
```

As an optimization, you could also move `messages` out of the loop, and call `messages.clear()` at the end of the loop. The advantage of this is that it will mean that `messages.resize()` will almost never need to allocate because you can reuse the memory. That means that that entire block of code in the middle of the function above will amount to a few measly pointer copies… which will be *FAST*… far faster than copying entire strings, even with `std::memcpy()`. And that in turn means much less time spent with the mutex locked, which means you should be able to get a *MUCH* higher throughput for your messages.

Comment: "*only two legal forms of `main()`*" is not quite true.  Compilers are permitted to accept other signatures for the main function - a common extension is `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` for example.  What is true is that the code presented is needlessly *non-portable*.

Comment: An infinite loop is not UB. An infinite loop _without a side effect_ is.

Comment: -1 because of the incorrect statements about `main()` and infinite loops, will +1 once that's fixed :) I would keep the bit about `std::list` short, just say that `std::vector` or `std::deque` might be fast because it avoids a lot of allocations and keeps things together in memory. As for copying the contents of the queue so you can process multiple messages in one go: why not just [`messages.swap(msg_queue)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap)?

Comment: 1) Extensions are not standard, and it would be misleading, if not incorrect, to call extensions “legal C++” just because the standard acknowledges the possibility of their existence. You can call it “legal C++-with-GCC-extensions” or “legal MSVC/Windows-flavour-C++” if you like, I suppose, but I wouldn’t do that kind of waffling when teaching, because it just sows confusion. 2) Yes, that’s true; my mistake. There are side effects here, so these infinite loops are not UB. Though, there’s still no way to portably end the program—that `th.join()` will (probably) never get executed.

Comment: 3) Thing is, because there are no comments, I’m not sure there *isn’t* a valid reason to use `std::list`. I’ve made concurrent message queues using (singly) linked lists before (so they can be lock-free). Maybe `std::list` is perfect for whatever the ultimate intended application here is.  I don’t like to presume cluelessness wantonly, so I try to explain the *usual* reasons why `std::list` isn’t right, so the reader can at least balance them with whatever reasons for using it they have in their head.

Comment: 4) Because they’re different types (`list` and `vector`). But even if they weren’t I might still do it that way, because if you swap the message queue with a new, empty one, then you’ll lose all the memory the queue already has. In other words, if you swap/move the queue itself, the next message will always trigger a new allocation; if you just swap/move the messages then clear, the queue still has its memory, and should only need to do a new allocation if the queue fills up with more messages than it had. (If you do the optimization, then this won’t really matter, and swapping would work.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But still: the implementation defined form of `main()` *is* legal C++. The version @TobySpeight mentioned is also not a compiler extension, it is a platform-specific version. Don't confuse "implementation defined" with "illegal".

Comment: As for 4), good point about the allocated memory. If both the queue itself and the temporary are a `vector`, then you could do something like `std::vector<...> messages; messages.reserve(msg_queue.capacity); messages.swap(msg_queue)`. If you also declare `messages` outside the loop, you need to call `msg_queue.clear()` somewhere in the loop, but you avoid unnecessary memory (re)allocations. If a `std::list` is used for both the queue and temporary, you can also [`swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/swap).

Comment: Don’t confuse implementation-defined *behaviour* with implementation-defined *extensions*. The former is legal C++ (valid everywhere) whose behaviour differs with the implementation. The latter is “anything goes”, and is not legal C++ almost by definition. The only reason the standard mentions non-standard forms of `main()` at all is because it has to: it clarifies that if you don’t use a standard form, you’re not allowed to use just anything as the entry point (like a label); it is constrained to *some* flavour of `main()`. The `**env` flavour is just a popular extension; it’s not even POSIX.